# could not find function "try_fetch"

Tags: r, plot, network-analysis, ggraph

I'm trying to create a Network plot but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code

```
graph_from_data_frame(d = word_correlations, 
                      vertices = abstract_which_mention_word %>%
                     semi_join(word_correlations, by = c("word" = "item1"))) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "fr") + 
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_node_text(aes (label = name), repel = TRUE)
```

R puts this error message

```
Error in try_fetch(as_tbl_graph(graph), error = function(e) { : 
  could not find function "try_fetch"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Re-installing rlang package worked for me. The try_fetch function is part of this. So a very simple solution, that I hope works!

`install.packages("rlang")`

`library(rlang)`

DHB.